# Finite semigroup

Tags: semigroups, finite-semigroups

Suppose that $a$ belongs to the finite semigroup $S$ (especially semigroups of transformations). Are there any techniques for determining the cardinality of  $SaS$?

> - Example: Let $S=\mathcal{T}_n$ (full transformation semigroup). We can write each idempotent $e= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
>   A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_r \\
>   a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_r 
>    \end{array} \right)(a_i\in A_i)$.

I'm wondering if $\mathcal{T}_ne\mathcal{T}_n$ is a helpful structure for computing the cardinality $\mathcal{T}_ne\mathcal{T}_n$ for each idempotent $e$. I'm not interested in the answer to this example.

Comment: Title: what is "finitie"?

Comment: 1ENIGMA1, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question.

Comment: @Angelo I add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very precise since you don't say how $S$ is given:
is it the semigroup generated by a given set of transformations, is the multiplication table already available, etc?

In any case, I invite you to read carefully the following article, which contains a number of useful algorithms and an extended bibliography on the topic:

J. East, A. Egri-Nagy, J.D. Mitchell, Y. Péresse, [Computing finite semigroups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717118300087), *J. Symbolic Comput.* **92** (2019), 110--155.

Note that if $S$ is a monoid, $SaS$ is the ideal generated by $a$. If $X$ is a generating set for $S$, you can compute it by constructing a sort of double-sided Cayley graph with root $a$ and edges of the form $s \xrightarrow{x} sx$ and $s \xrightarrow{x} xs$, where $s \in S$ and $x \in X$.